# Xbee Explorer Regulated (WRL-11373) - Current draw

Tags: current, xbee

Can anyone tell me roughly how much current the WRL-11373 draws?  I've googled and looked on [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11373) but can't find any info on it. It says [here](https://www.generationrobots.com/en/402383-xbee-explorer-regulated-module.html) that the max supply current is 500 mA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The module 5 V to 3.3 V regulator. Source: [XBee Regulated - V14](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Regulated-v14.pdf).*

The 500 mA specification is the maximum the board can *supply* at 3.3 V, not what the board itself consumes. This is determined by the MIC5219 voltage regulator.

Actual consumption of the board will be the tiny current required by the level shifters (if I understand its function correctly) and whatever the board is feeding at 3.3 V.

Comment: I'll be using the XBee Explorer Regulated to power/control an [XBee Pro S1](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8742) which consumes 55 mA.  So I would add this to the level shifter current draw nA or μA?

Comment: So your board will need a 55 mA supply then.